# Mystery value returned by pygame.Color()

Tags: python, colors, pygame

I need to identify a pixel's color as sampled from an element in a PixelArray then fed into pygame.Color(). One of the values returned by pygame.Color() has me puzzled.

I've studied the integer value held in the selected element of the pixel array, translating the value into binary and identifying the RGB components. All three components can be accounted for. A call to pygame.Color(pixel_integer) returns all three values along with an extra value (a zero) in the from of (0, R, G, B). That zero has me baffled. Can someone identify what this value represents. Hue? Saturation? Both? Neither? Something else entirely? Why zero?

```
from os import system
import pygame


system('cls') # Clear greeting from CC screen.

usecolor = (46,12,187,255)       # Declare our chosen color.
sprite = pygame.Surface((10,10)) # Greate a surface. Let us call it a 'sprite'.
sprite.fill(usecolor)            # Fill the 'sprite' with our chosen color.

array = pygame.PixelArray(sprite)   # Create a pixel array of the sprite, locking the sprite.
sample = array[5,5]                 # Sample the integer holding the color values of pixel [5,5]
del array                           # Delete the pixel array, unlocking the sprite.

print("\n Challenge: Use a pixel-array of a sprite to sample the color of the pixel at location [5,5]")
print("            Determine the RGB-values held by the integer found there.") 

print("\n We have created a 100x100 'sprite' and filled it with the color "+str(usecolor))
print(" Then we cerated a pixel array of the sprite and sampled the color of the element at location [5,5],")
print(" corrosponding to pixel [5,5] on the sprite.")

print("\n The color we used to fill the sprite was",usecolor)
print(" The value sampled from pixel [5,5] is",sample)
print(" pygame.Color(sample) =",pygame.Color(sample))

print("\n Notice that there is a mystery zero at the front of the values returned by pygame.Color().")
print(" Notice too that our Alpha value is missing from the back.")
print(" (Let us ignore the missing alpha value. It doesn't matter.)")

print("\n m,r,g,b = pygame.Color(sample) where 'm' stands for 'mystery'")
m,r,g,b = pygame.Color(sample)

print("\n m >>",m)
print(" r >>",r)
print(" g >>",g)
print(" b >>",b)
color = (r,g,b)

print("\n From these values we find that color =",color)

print("\n Question: What is 'm'?")
print("\n 'm' can't be alpha because that value would be 255 (opaque); an alpha value of 0 is transparent.")
print(" Besides, the alpha value should be at the end of the color series, not at the beginning. Any ideas?")
print("\n\n\tThanks!\n\n       -Science_1")

print('',end="\n ")
exit()
```

There are no errors, but the lead-zero value that has me baffled. What causes it and what does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In documentation for [Color](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html) you can read that it is alpha channel.

But `Surface` doesn't have to use `alpha` value if screen doesn't work in 32bit mode - `RGBA`.

You can set 32bit mode

```
pygame.display.set_mode( ..., depth=32)
```

And you can also convert surface to `RGBA` using `.convert_alpha()`

```
sprite = pygame.Surface((10,10)).convert_alpha()
```

but it works only if you use `set_mode()`.

This code shows `alpha = 255`. But if you remove `.convert_alpha()` then it shows `alpha = 0` again

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), depth=32)

usecolor = (46, 12, 187, 255)
sprite = pygame.Surface((10,10)).convert_alpha()
sprite.fill(usecolor)

array = pygame.PixelArray(sprite)
sample = array[5,5]

a,r,g,b = pygame.Color(sample)

print(" pygame.Color(sample) =", pygame.Color(sample))
print(" r >>", r)
print(" g >>", g)
print(" b >>", b)
print(" a >>", a)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you furas, that is very interesting. I will try setting the depth to 32 and then experimenting with it to see if that mystery zero is indeed the alpha value. That would account for why the alhpa went missing. (It's just strange that it would appear at the front of the RGB values rather than at the end.)

Comment: PS: I had much of your code in my program but stripped it out (and so much more) as unnecessary for the purpose of asking my question; but I never had the depth set and I didn't try the convert, which could be the key. The reference material for .Color() was mum on the value/ordering issue and left me scratching my head. Thanks again.

Comment: The .convert_alpha() does the trick in allowing the alpha value to be revealed. The pixel-array returns a negative value (the high-bit being set) and pygame.Color() chokes and dies on the negative value, but the command sprite.get_at((5,5)) returns the (R,G,B,A) just fine. Between the PixelArray method I had (were the alpha-value leads and reads as zero) and the answer you provided, I am confident I have everything I need to go either way. Decoding the negative value so that it can be fed to pygame.Color() is just busy work for another day. I consider my current question answered. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Given the information provided, the pixel in question is most likely black, or empty.